# Let $a,b \in Z^+$, let $c = {ab}/{\gcd(a,b)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a,b \in Z^+$, let $c = {ab}/{\gcd(a,b)}$ Show that:

i) If $a\mid d$ and $b\mid d$ then $c\mid d$

ii) $c=\min\{d \in Z^+ \text{ such that }a\mid d \wedge b\mid d\}$

Comment: If $a\vert d$, then there exists an $x\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ax=d$. If $b\vert d$, then there exists a $y\in\Bbb Z$ such that $by=d$. Then, what's $ab$? What's the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$? The second part is telling you that $c$ is the lowest common multiple.

Comment: algebraically $ab = d^2/xy$. I've tried subbing that into the second part of the equation but now i'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a' = \frac a{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $b' = \frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Claim 1:  $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

Proof:  $K=\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a',b')$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ so $K\le \gcd(a,b)$ so $\gcd(a',b') = 1$.

Claim 2:  If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $m|nk$ then $m|k$.

Pf: Intuitively $m$ and $n$ have no factors in common so the only factors $m$ has in common with $nk$ are factors of $k$.  You can do this formally with prime powers dividing $m$ must all divide $k$ as they can't divide $n$.  Or we can do it with Bezout's Lemma:  there are $a,b$ so that $am+bn=1$ so $mj=nk$ so $bmj=bnk=k-amk$ so $m(bj-ak)=k$ and $m|k$.

....

So now... we just do it.

$a = a'\gcd(a,b)$ and $b=b'\gcd(a,b)$ and

$a|d$ means there is an $m$ so that $am = d$ and $b|d$ means there is a $n$ so that $bn = d$.

So $a'\gcd(a,b)m = b'\gcd(a,b)n = d$.  So $a'm = b'n = \frac {d}{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $\gcd(a,b)|d$.

$a'm = b'n$ so $a'|b'n$ but $\gcd(a',b') =1$ so $a'|n$ and, likewise, $b'|m$.

SO let $m = b'm'$ and $n = a'n'$ and we have:

$d = ab'm' = ba'n'$.  Where $ab' = a\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}=\frac {ab}{\gcd(a,b)} = b\frac a{\gcd(a,b)} = ba'$.  So $c = \frac {ab}{\gcd(a,b)}= a'b=b'a$.

So $d = cm'=cn'$ and $c|d$ (and $n'=m'$ by the way).

....

ii) If $a|d$ and $b|d$ then $a=a'\gcd(a,b)$ and $b=b'\gcd(a,b)$ so $a'|d$ and $b'|d$ and $\gcd(a,b)|d$.

So the least common multiple of $a', b', \gcd(a,b)$ divides $d$. and least common multiple of $a',b'\gcd(a,b) = a'b'\gcd(a,b) =c$.